Getting Authentication Error Accessing Microsoft Teams Presence API in Graph Explorer - Microsoft 365 Requirement?
I'm trying to access presence information in Microsoft Teams using the Microsoft Graph API via Graph Explorer. Specifically, I'm calling:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/presence
However, I keep encountering an AuthenticationError with the following response
{
"error": {
"code": "AuthenticationError",
"message": "Error authenticating with resource",
"innerError": {
"date": "2024-11-11T11:17:17",
"request-id": "2f867d6f-0d55-4ddc-b710-5cd4a20a30f1",
"client-request-id": "4363c731-e866-2144-15f0-7567055f1160"
}
}
}
I’ve tried the following:
Verified that I’m logged in to Graph Explorer with my Microsoft account.
Checked "Modify Permissions" in Graph Explorer but didn't see options for Presence.Read or Presence.Read.All.
Ensured I'm using the /v1.0 endpoint, and also tried the /beta endpoint.
Questions:
Is presence data accessible only with Microsoft 365 (work or school) accounts? I’m currently using a personal Microsoft account.
If Microsoft 365 is required, what permissions do I need, and do these require admin consent?

Yes you need a account with M365/O365 license and you need Global admin role to grant admin consent

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
But for me this link will Work and Return Some Details  my ID

Yes that will work

But my colleague can access Outlook without any subscription.

Try with work or school account not personal account

Refer this MsDoc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions presence API do not support Personal accounts

I need to check my API in Microsoft Graph Explorer, but it does not allow me to log in with my work or school email. How can I check it?

What is the issue?

I tried to Sign in ,it ask Work or School /Personal  ,i go with Work or School, And Entered my Password ,But it didn't sign in

Not sure about it as it must work

We strongly recommend you add a personal account to your Learn profile to ensure you can continue to access your learning progress regardless of your employment or academic status. You can have up to five school or work accounts and one personal account linked to your profile to use for signing in.
this is the Warning

My task is simple: I need to set or get my Teams presence or status message using C# in my own application.

Could you please refer this sample - https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-change-notification/csharp. As mentioned above by @Rukmini presence API do not support Personal accounts.
